# Cast (listbox)sender

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to know what is happening below:

```
ListBox listboxNames = (ListBox)sender;
```

What I understand from this is: A dynamic listbox is created.

But what does the sender do, and why is that being cast by `(ListBox)`?

Comment: Explicit type casts (`(TypeName)x`, `x as TypeName`) do not create new objects.  All they do is to give the compiler and/or runtime environment a clue what type some object `x` supposedly has.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's taking the variable `sender` (which is probably due to your function probably being a handler for an event, am I right)? and casting it to the type `ListBox`, and putting that value into a variable called `listboxNames`. The reason this works is basically due to the parameter `sender` being a `ListBox`, but it had to be converted to an object to be able to send it to a function without having to make a load of overloads (this was before generics were available). However, the cast lets you get it back to its original type.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the `sender` is the object that throws the event. In your case its probably the ListBox and thats why you can cast it to ListBox. So it's not any special magic object, but the actual ListBox which is passed into your method 'disguised' as a general object.

So you don't create a dynamic object, but as you know it has to be the ListBox, you can cast it safely and use it. But be aware, that its the same ListBox which you have in your GUI, so any changes you make to it will be reflected in your GUI.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `sender` is mostly likely a parameter in an event handler like this:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // sender only provides access to Object members
    // radioButton provdes access to all members available to RadioButtons
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)sender;
}
```

Yes? In event handlers, `sender` is a reference to the object that generated the event. In your example, it is a ListBox. In mine, it is a RadioButton. But since `sender` is typed as an object in the handler, you only have access to a small subset of the available properties and methods for that particular instance. The only way to get access to all the functions available for a ListBox or RadioButton or whatever, is to cast it to that type. Note that no new object is created here. In your example `sender` *is* a ListBox; you are merely creating a new variable which points to the same object instance and provides access to all the members of ListBox.